# Does the order of HTML attributes have any effect on performance?

Tags: performance, html

Is there any reason that relates to parsing time, layout, rendering time, style application, etc. to have HTML attributes in a certain (or consistent) order?

The order of HTML attributes [does not improve a page's compressibility significantly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3951372/optimized-order-of-html-attributes-for-compression), and maintaining some order can make the markup easier for human readers to figure out (e.g. putting `id` first, starting `<input>`s with `type`, putting boolean attributes at the end of an opening tag) but I'd like to know if there are any performance reasons to consider attribute order.

Comment: Might potentially be something to ask a high performance expert like http://www.stevesouders.com/blog/ - if you're still curious, that is.

Comment: Unrelated, but if you are looking for a standard for ordering the HTML attributes, see this - https://stackoverflow.com/a/69114392/4010017

Answer (score 3, accepted):

None to speak of I don't think. All the properties within each tag have to be parsed and read before the tag can be properly understood by the browser.

As long as the code is syntax-error free and (obviously) the shorter the better.

Comment: Yeah. The [XML Recommendation states](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#sec-starttags) that "the order of attribute specifications… is not significant."

Answer (score 2):

It all depends on the layout engine, but i suspect it would be negligible. You should not be concerned with this.